# Calculate Sum of BST in a Range

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code. Its returning 25 for testcase
Given the root node of a binary search tree, return the sum of values of all nodes with value between L and R (inclusive).

The binary search tree is guaranteed to have unique values.
Input: root = [10,5,15,3,7,null,18], L = 7, R = 15
Output: 32
My output:25

```
class Solution:
    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:
        self.sum1=0
        self.traverse(root,L,R)
        return self.sum1
    def traverse(self,node,L,R):
        if node:
            if L<=node.val<=R:
                self.sum1+=node.val
                if L<node.val:
                    self.traverse(node.left,L,R)
                if node.val<R:
                    self.traverse(node.right,L,R)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `left child` and `right child` only when current `node.value` lies between range `l` and `r`. You have call them even if `node.value` does not lie between `l` and `r`.

So change the `indentation` of `if` blocks inside `traverse()` method.

check below code.

```
class Solution:
    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:
        self.sum1=0
        self.traverse(root,L,R)
        return self.sum1
    def traverse(self,node,L,R):
        if node:
            if L<=node.val<=R:
                self.sum1+=node.val
            if L<node.val:
                self.traverse(node.left,L,R)
            if node.val<R:
                self.traverse(node.right,L,R)
```

Comment: oh Yes! Thanks for helping me out

Comment: @pruthvikreddyElemati please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help